# Best Practice: Where to store static function declarations

Tags: c, header

I was searching for a while and couldn't find any hints.

I am wondering right now: what is a common way of dealing with static function declarations in C? Because static functions aren't accessible from any other module than that which defines the function. I am not sure where to declare it.

My thoughts so far reached the following possibilities, where I could declare a static function:

- Put them in the public header, that acts as an interface to that module.
- Put them inside the .c source file, in which it is used.
- Put them in a separate header file, which is only used by that specific module.

Are there any suggestions on that out there?

Comment: If you use a header file (e.g. to avoid huge source files), then make sure that one module is the only one `#include`ing it. You could use a naming convention for this such as `foo.private.h` should only be `#include`d by `foo.c`

Comment: @Brandin I like this Approach. It solves exactly the Problem that has caused the issue to me. The basic intention was to seperate the pure implementation from (possibly) huge definitions. Thank you for this proposal.

Comment: @Brandin other than a naming convention, do you know of any `#define` magic that could enforce something like that? Not to the point of a security measure, but as a `#error` or something if you accidentally `#include foo.private.h` in a file that you shouldn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the declaration of your static function inside the .c source file, in which it is defined and used. No other module will use it, so no other module needs to include the declaration, so there is no need to have it in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

In C, if I'm using static functions, I prefer to have no separate declaration. I define the functions before they are used. This way, I find the code much easier to understand - a kind of building from blocks approach.
So, obviously no header ever knows about them.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on your use case.

When I make an interface that is used by more then one .c file then I put those directly into the header that also has the typedefs, structs, .... Keep in mind that `static` functions that are not used will not be included into the object file.

If you use them only within one compilation unit then there is no reason not to put thmm just there.

Comment: Why would you put `static` things in an _interface_? Sounds a bit contradictory to me.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo if for example I have a complex `struct` and a simple function that initialises or destroys that `struct`. I will need that initialiser in every compilation unit that uses that `struct` and it is too small to have it's own callable symbol, so I make it `static inline` and put it into the header along with the struct.

Comment: Interesting use of `static inline`.  Still, if the header file's inclusion is potentially pervasive, what does calling it `static` help.  Why not simply `inline`?